# “So do I” vs. “me either”

Tags: difference

What is the difference between **“so do I”** and **“me either”**?

For instance:

> “I think this is bad.”
>
> **“So do I.”**

Answer (score 4):

*Me either* is an unusual (and chiefly American) colloquialism with the same meaning as *me neither*, i.e. it is used to suggest that some attribute does not apply to the speaker as well as to some other person under discussion (or maybe the person to whom the speaker is speaking).

*So do I* is a common expression used in both American and British English to suggest that some attribute applies to both the speaker and the other person under discussion.

Therefore, they are in some sense opposites.

Comment: Can somebody explain the downvote please?  This is a valid answer that adds the missing information that "me either" is chiefly US usage that is missing from the other answer.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. I think it's a good answer.

Comment: Though I'm not the downvoter, I believe that claiming that "Me either" is unusual is unusual. Though the colloquialism claim is probably right, and probably so is the part "chiefly American". Checking "Me either" vs "Me neither" on Google Ngram is easy for it's case-sensitive.

Comment: Here are the graphs for [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Me+either%2CMe+neither&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMe%20either%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMe%20neither%3B%2Cc0) and [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Me+either%2CMe+neither&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMe%20either%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMe%20neither%3B%2Cc0). According to the graphs, I don't think that "Me either" is unusual at all.

Comment: @starsplusplus I don't know if you can see the other answer which is now deleted by the owner. Imho, the other answer is better, and it received more upvotes than this one. That doesn't mean that I think this answer is particularly bad or anything.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to show that we agree with a positive statement we can "So do I" or  or "I do, too" or"Me, too"Example: I like ice-cream" "So do I" or "I do, too"  or"ME, too"
When we want to show that we agree with a negative statement we use "Neither/Nor do I"or "I don't ,either" or "Me either" Example: "I don't like ice-cream". Neither/Nor do I". or "I don't, either" or "Me, either" So, as one can see, the difference of "So do I" and "Me ,either", is that the first is a response to a positive sentence, whereas, the latter is a response to a negative one.